# Hashtag Generator is not working

Tags: javascript

не работает программа, я скорее всего где-то в алгоритме ошиблась. Нужно создать функцию которая будет из заданных в массив слов делать хэштэг и чтобы каждое новое слово начиналось с большой буквы.
Пример : To be or not --> #ToBeOrNot

```js
function generateHashtag(str) {

  let wordArray = ['to be or not to be'];
  let hash = '#';
  if(wordArray.length ===0||wordArray.length > 140){
    return false;
  }
  
  else{
    for(let i =0; i<wordArray.length;i++){
      wordArray.forEach((element,i) => {
        if(i==" "){
          let final = hash+ element.toUpperCase().join();
          console.log(final);
          return final;
        }
        
      });
    }
  }
}
```